# making a wizard interface in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, wizard

I'm using delphi 7 and I'm trying to make a wizard interface. I don't know if there is an easier way to make a wizard, so I was thinking of making separate forms for each step of the wizard, and when the user clicks "Next" the active form closes and the next one opens.

Here's a screen-shot of two successive forms: [image: screen-shot]

I've made a procedure that take 2 forms as parameters: the form that will be closed and the next form of the wizard

```
class Procedure Tspad.nextForm(showForm, closeForm: TForm);
begin
   closeForm.Close;
   showForm.Showmodal;
end;
```

When I click the "Next" Button the folowing code is executed:

```
Tspad.nextForm(echipContractForm, clientContractForm);
```

When i run the program, and i press the "Next" button, the next form apeares but the curent one dosen't close.

How can i make this work, or is there another more efficient way to create a wizard?

Comment: Use TPageControl : http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/hidepagectrltab.htm

Comment: Project Jedi (JVCL) has a wizard component called [TJvWizard](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvWizard).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One very common way to make a wizard is to use a page control. Each distinct page of the wizard is a different page/tabsheet in the page control. I believe that this is effectively how Windows implements wizards.

Naturally you want to hide all the tabs. Do this by setting `TabVisible` to `False` for each tabsheet. When you wish to move forwards and backwards through the wizard, e.g. when the user clicks the next or previous buttons, effect this by setting `ActivePage` or `ActivePageIndex` depending on your preference.

Comment: This is how I've done it in the past. Have a separate form for your wizard, with the page control and some buttons.

Comment: i agree with this but also with LaKraven's idea to make a form per page, and dock the pages at runtime.  Otherwise wizards tend to turn into a giant ball of spaghetti.

Comment: @Warren LaKraven is actually suggesting frames rather than forms and I presume docking them at design time. But either way works and can be a very good technique to keep the spaghetti at bay, I agree.

Comment: For better results you could set DoubleBuffered to true.

Answer (score 14):

A good practise for the division of content being displayed on a single form is the use of *Frames*.

A *Frame* is a lot like a form, except it has no Window of its own, but rather sits inside a *host Form*.

When combined with (as David Heffernan has suggested) a `TPageControl` or even a `TNotebook` (*which is pretty-much exactly the same as `TPageControl`, only it doesn't have Tabs to begin with*), you end up with an easily-maintainable Wizard.

Comment: +1 but `TNotebook` is a bit of an oddity. It looks legacy to me and is perhaps a little harder to use.

Comment: I mention it because I cannot remember if TPageControl actually exists in Delphi 7 (I use it a LOT these days, but cannot remember ever seeing it circa Delphi 7)

Comment: Yes it was present in D7 and long before then too

Comment: Good to know :)
TNotebook is in the Win 3.1 tab, so yes... I would suggest it's legacy ;)

Comment: great :) I'd strongly suggest marking David's as the correct answer, since mine is more an expansion on his ;)

Answer (score 11):

JVCL has a good control to make a wizard in a very simple and effective way (TJvWizard). See http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/

Comment: Agreed.  Saves you a lot of time reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

You can give a try to these :

- [Balmsoft Wizard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bswizard/) released under LGPL.
- [Delphi Wizard Framework](http://code.google.com/p/delphiwizardframework/) by SO member [Steven R. Kamradt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9217/skamradt).

Answer (score 2):

You can test some components that can help you with this task (internally using tPageControl or TNotebook).  See [this link](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=262).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider TMS [TAdvSmoothStepControl](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothstepcontrol.asp) (not free !). 
Another solution, but only 'external' to your program, is to use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to make a Wizard, even for 'non installation setup' purposes.

In fact with Inno Setup you can make a lot of thinks ( modify .ini file and registry, start/stop programs...) that can be usefull for a wizard without 'installing' a program.

Comment: The last statement in your answer presumes the OP is trying to produce an Installation Wizard. The screenshots suggest otherwise. I suggest editing that part of your answer out and leaving the recommendation of TAdvSmoothStepControl (which is a nice component for sure)

Comment: @LaKraven While the main use for Inno Setup is to create an installation setup, you may also use it (with some hack) as a Wizard for simple operations, like close a program, change .ini files according to user choices, and run the program again. May be it is not clear for all and I'll edit my answer.