# issues with wizard in delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using delphi  and I'm trying to make a wizard interface., I was thinking of making separate forms for each step of the wizard, and when the user clicks "Next" the active form. The problem I have shrink the window to max and then click next on the next form am unable to view the buttons at bottom until I resize the form.

My question is that if I shrink the form and hit next button it takes me to another but the buttons (next, back, finish) are not visible until I resize the second form

This is how the problem looks:

Comment: maybe on fix form with the buttons prevoius,next,cancel and finish as container for the separate forms will be a better solution.

Comment: I just started learning delphi, am not following you so can you please be more specific.

Comment: JediVCL has JvWizard component, ex-KWizard
Looks nice, though tuning it is no comfort work

Answer (score 0):

When designing Wizards I prefer to use Page Control.

The basic idea is: each tab is a Wizard Page. When the user clicks "Next" you show the next TAB in the Page Control and hide the previous one.

Please, note that if you have too many pages it would be nightmare to manage them. Then you may use Frames instead of Page Control.

@David-Heffernan has explained it here: [making a wizard interface in delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384731/1022219)

To make it reusable you can create an Interface that defines base Wizard functionality like:

- Go to Next Page
- Go to Previous Page
- On Page Load
- On Page Unload
- On Wizard Start
- On Wizard End

etc.